# Using a non-capturing group between two matches?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Given the following text (note the newline character):

```
 foo bar foo5 bar foo-bar foo qux quux\n foo
```

I wish to get all matches for `foo` and `qux quux`, expect in the cases any of these appears next to a digit, letter, or underscore, i.e.

**foo** bar foo5 bar **foo**-bar **foo** **qux quux**\n bar **foo**

Using the following regex:

```regex
(?:\W)(foo|qux quux)(?:\W|$)
```

I get a match for all desired occurrences of `foo`:

**foo** bar foo5 bar **foo**-bar **foo** qux quux\n bar **foo**

The problem is that I don't get a match for `qux quux`, since the single whitespace that precedes it has already been matched as a non-capturing group (`?:`) of the 3rd match:

```
 ...
 Match 3
   Full match: " foo "
   Group 1   : "foo"
 ...
```

How can I also get `qux quux`?

NOTE: I understand that by inserting 2 whitespaces between `foo` and `qux quux` would make my regex work, but this is silly.

Comment: Replace `\W` by `\b` or use lookbehind and lookahead

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Would gladly accept your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries, that does what you are looking for. Like this:

```
\b(foo|qux quux)\b
```

Here is a little example you can play with:

https://regex101.com/r/oYeixv/1

And a nice write up of what a word boundary is: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html